# Don't understand Z/x z/y partial derivative question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

$\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}$I have to find $\dd z/\dd x$ and $\dd z/\dd y$ for $z = f(x) + g(y)$ and for $z = f(x + y)$. The answers for (a) are $f'(x)$ and $g'(y)$; for (b), both answers are $f'(x + y)$. I don't understand this question and how they got these. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Google on "partial derivatives." May also need chain rule multivariate case.

Comment: @Terysd: I added the partial derivative symbols, and made a couple of changes to correct what seemed to be typos in the original. When you get the chance, please check to be sure everything matches your intent.

Comment: Ayes, that is correct. Thanks